# How to use a backup in OpenVZ

Tags: virtual-machine, openvz

I have a backup (.tgz file) that is an openvz virtual machine. i followed this [article](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-and-using-openvz-on-centos-6.3) and i setup an openvz container but how i will use my backup file?

**EDIT:**
i found the tool [ovz-web-panel](http://code.google.com/p/ovz-web-panel/) (i am new to openvz :) )

Answer (score 3):

To restore the machine you could use `vzrestore` or `vzdump`, the example restores it to CT 600:

```
vzrestore /space/backup/vzdump-123.tar 600
```

or

```
vzdump --restore /space/backup/vzdump-777.tar 600
```